# Possible to slow down a PowerShell Recursive Search?

Tags: powershell

This is going to be a weird one for ya.

I need to rate limit or slow down a powershell one liner that I am using to search a local file system, as well as network shares in an enterprise environment. I would like to slow down the search to minimize the possibility of network impact.

The script searches files (mostly document or text files) for certain keywords and phrases. Getting this done quickly is not an issue as I am not on a time crunch, safety is key.

Here is the one liner:

```
Get-ChildItem -path C:\ -recurse -Filter *.txt -ErrorAction Continue | Select-String -Pattern "xxxx" | select filename, Linenumber, Line, Path | Format-Table
```

Comment: Without seeing it, build a delay into the function so it recursively delays . . . .

Answer (score 2):

With your code added then, I think I was on the right track. With your original code (formatted a bit):

```
Get-ChildItem -path C:\ -recurse -Filter *.txt -ErrorAction Continue | 
    ForEach-Item -Process {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        $_
    } |
    Select-String -Pattern "xxxx" | 
    select filename, Linenumber, Line, Path | 
    Format-Table
```

Want to make it look more idiomatic? Write your own function that accepts pipeline input and delays execution. I might even use [a `filter` which is a shorthand way of writing a pipeline-aware function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-6#filters):

```
filter Delay-Object ([int]$Milliseconds) {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $Milliseconds
    $_
}

Get-ChildItem -path C:\ -recurse -Filter *.txt -ErrorAction Continue | 
    Delay-Object -Milliseconds 1000 |
    Select-String -Pattern "xxxx" | 
    select filename, Linenumber, Line, Path | 
    Format-Table
```

---

Without your code this is pure speculation but let's say you're doing something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem \\my\share\*.* | ForEach-Object {
    # do your search here
}
```

You can just introduce a delay right into your iteration:

```
Get-ChildItem \\my\share\*.* | ForEach-Object {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    # do your search here
}
```

If you're not using your own script block, let's say you're using `Select-String`:

```
Get-ChildItem \\my\share\*.* | Select-String findme
```

Then the solution is the same: insert a `ForEach-Object`!

```
Get-ChildItem \\my\share\*.* | 
    ForEach-Object {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        $_  # have to return the original object back to the pipeline
    } |
    Select-String findme
```

You might be thinking that `Get-ChildItem` is going to find all the files first and pass them all along and that even that will be too much stress on the network drives, but the pipeline doesn't work that way. <sup>*</sup>

Each item found is going to be passed to the next command in the pipeline one by one, so your delays will happen *between* each item. Therefore, you can basically insert a delay between any pipeline commands.

<sup>* some pipeline commands like `Sort-Object` need to collect all of the items and then pass them all out at once; from the POV of the next commands it still looks the same, but it will change how/where you need to put delays.</sup>

Comment: Ahh thank you. I see where you are getting at. I will try your ideas tomorrow.

Comment: @ActiveMeasures cool, added a nice edit at the top since you posted your code

Comment: Well done. `Get-ChildItem` _does_ collect a given directory's items up front, because it sorts them for predictable output - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/c857392c34613fc8ece1432ceb89a5310d9e5fd9/src/System.Management.Automation/namespaces/FileSystemProvider.cs#L1618 That said, in a recursive search each individual directory's items are still sent to the pipeline before moving on to the next directory.

Comment: Thanks @mklement0 that is a good point. In a large directory there will still be a bit of filesystem pressure because of that. At least this should throttle the heavier I/O of reading the file contents.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke-command has a -throttle parameter which might help. It limits the number of threads so might help limit the throughput.

Comment: The `-ThrottleLimit` parameter applies to targeting multiple remote computers simultaneously. It doesn't throttle individual commands on the local machine, which is what the OP is after.

Comment: This is good though because in the future I was going to attempt this script on a small network

Comment: @ActiveMeasures do note this only applies to using PowerShell remoting against computers, and it throttles _by computer_ (on which PowerShell is executing) so it's not going to understand UNC paths that connect to different file servers for instance. Worth looking into if you'll be doing that kind of remoting though.